# GraphQL query for Drupal - node where field value

Tags: graphql, drupal-8

I'm trying to understand if there is a way to structure a GraphQL query that will allow me to get results based on a value on a field.

If I do a general query like:

```
nodeQuery(filter: {conditions: {field: "type", value: "unit_descriptor", operator: EQUAL}}) {
    entities {
      ...on NodeUnitDescriptor {
        nid
        title
        fieldParentSpec{
          targetId
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I get this:

```
  "data": {
    "nodeQuery": {
      "entities": [
        {
          "nid": 220,
          "title": "Unit 1: Professional Practice",
          "fieldParentSpec": {
            "targetId": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "nid": 223,
          "title": "Unit 2: My Second Unit",
          "fieldParentSpec": {
            "targetId": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "nid": 245,
          "title": "Unit 3: Third Unit",
          "fieldParentSpec": {
            "targetId": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

What I'd like to be able to do is pass the `targetId` in a query and get back all of the entities that are have the `fieldParentSpec.targetId` of the value passed into the query.

Is that possible? What does that look like?

(From a GraphQL newbie) Thanks